# Kubernetes authentication using Keystone (--experimental-keystone-url)

Tags: kubernetes, keystone

I have a Kubernetes cluster setup on coreOS. I've added the option `--experimental-keystone-url` which is set to keystone url and version 2.0 to my kube-apiserver config to enable Keystone Authentication. But by adding this option the kube-apiserver won't start. Any settings I may be missing here?

** EDIT **
Logs with `v=9`

```
I1006 09:53:55.637447   55310 round_trippers.go:299] curl -k -v -XGET  -H "Accept: application/json, */*" -H "User-Agent: kubectl/v1.3.3 (darwin/amd64) kubernetes/c641139" http://10.240.126.13:8080/api
I1006 09:53:55.718256   55310 round_trippers.go:318] GET http://10.240.126.13:8080/api 200 OK in 80 milliseconds
I1006 09:53:55.718294   55310 round_trippers.go:324] Response Headers:
I1006 09:53:55.718303   55310 round_trippers.go:327]     Content-Type: application/json
I1006 09:53:55.718314   55310 round_trippers.go:327]     Date: Thu, 06 Oct 2016 16:53:54 GMT
I1006 09:53:55.718326   55310 round_trippers.go:327]     Content-Length: 131
I1006 09:53:55.718389   55310 request.go:891] Response Body: {"kind":"APIVersions","versions":["v1"],"serverAddressByClientCIDRs":[{"clientCIDR":"0.0.0.0/0","serverAddress":"10.0.0.4:6443"}]}
I1006 09:53:55.718713   55310 round_trippers.go:299] curl -k -v -XGET  -H "Accept: application/json, */*" -H "User-Agent: kubectl/v1.3.3 (darwin/amd64) kubernetes/c641139" http://10.240.126.13:8080/apis
I1006 09:53:55.800450   55310 round_trippers.go:318] GET http://10.240.126.13:8080/apis 200 OK in 81 milliseconds
I1006 09:53:55.800488   55310 round_trippers.go:324] Response Headers:
I1006 09:53:55.800497   55310 round_trippers.go:327]     Date: Thu, 06 Oct 2016 16:53:55 GMT
I1006 09:53:55.800509   55310 round_trippers.go:327]     Content-Length: 1625
I1006 09:53:55.800520   55310 round_trippers.go:327]     Content-Type: application/json
I1006 09:53:55.800587   55310 request.go:891] Response Body: {"kind":"APIGroupList","groups":[{"name":"apps","versions":[{"groupVersion":"apps/v1alpha1","version":"v1alpha1"}],"preferredVersion":{"groupVersion":"apps/v1alpha1","version":"v1alpha1"},"serverAddressByClientCIDRs":[{"clientCIDR":"0.0.0.0/0","serverAddress":"10.0.0.4:6443"}]},{"name":"autoscaling","versions":[{"groupVersion":"autoscaling/v1","version":"v1"}],"preferredVersion":{"groupVersion":"autoscaling/v1","version":"v1"},"serverAddressByClientCIDRs":[{"clientCIDR":"0.0.0.0/0","serverAddress":"10.0.0.4:6443"}]},{"name":"batch","versions":[{"groupVersion":"batch/v1","version":"v1"},{"groupVersion":"batch/v2alpha1","version":"v2alpha1"}],"preferredVersion":{"groupVersion":"batch/v1","version":"v1"},"serverAddressByClientCIDRs":[{"clientCIDR":"0.0.0.0/0","serverAddress":"10.0.0.4:6443"}]},{"name":"extensions","versions":[{"groupVersion":"extensions/v1beta1","version":"v1beta1"}],"preferredVersion":{"groupVersion":"extensions/v1beta1","version":"v1beta1"},"serverAddressByClientCIDRs":[{"clientCIDR":"0.0.0.0/0","serverAddress":"10.0.0.4:6443"}]},{"name":"policy","versions":[{"groupVersion":"policy/v1alpha1","version":"v1alpha1"}],"preferredVersion":{"groupVersion":"policy/v1alpha1","version":"v1alpha1"},"serverAddressByClientCIDRs":[{"clientCIDR":"0.0.0.0/0","serverAddress":"10.0.0.4:6443"}]},{"name":"rbac.authorization.k8s.io","versions":[{"groupVersion":"rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1alpha1","version":"v1alpha1"}],"preferredVersion":{"groupVersion":"rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1alpha1","version":"v1alpha1"},"serverAddressByClientCIDRs":[{"clientCIDR":"0.0.0.0/0","serverAddress":"10.0.0.4:6443"}]}]}
I1006 09:53:55.801876   55310 round_trippers.go:299] curl -k -v -XGET  -H "Accept: application/json, */*" -H "User-Agent: kubectl/v1.3.3 (darwin/amd64) kubernetes/c641139" http://10.240.126.13:8080/api/v1/nodes
I1006 09:53:55.885365   55310 round_trippers.go:318] GET http://10.240.126.13:8080/api/v1/nodes 200 OK in 83 milliseconds
I1006 09:53:55.885409   55310 round_trippers.go:324] Response Headers:
I1006 09:53:55.885425   55310 round_trippers.go:327]     Content-Type: application/json
I1006 09:53:55.885439   55310 round_trippers.go:327]     Date: Thu, 06 Oct 2016 16:53:55 GMT
I1006 09:53:55.885531   55310 request.go:891] Response Body: {"kind":"NodeList","apiVersion":"v1","metadata":{"selfLink":"/api/v1/nodes","resourceVersion":"711"},"items":[{"metadata":{"name":"10.0.0.5","selfLink":"/api/v1/nodes/10.0.0.5","uid":"1228dcb6-8be5-11e6-a1ca-fa163ebf0693","resourceVersion":"709","creationTimestamp":"2016-10-06T16:51:04Z","labels":{"beta.kubernetes.io/arch":"amd64","beta.kubernetes.io/os":"linux","kubernetes.io/hostname":"10.0.0.5"},"annotations":{"volumes.kubernetes.io/controller-managed-attach-detach":"true"}},"spec":{"externalID":"10.0.0.5"},"status":{"capacity":{"alpha.kubernetes.io/nvidia-gpu":"0","cpu":"1","memory":"4051648Ki","pods":"110"},"allocatable":{"alpha.kubernetes.io/nvidia-gpu":"0","cpu":"1","memory":"4051648Ki","pods":"110"},"conditions":[{"type":"OutOfDisk","status":"False","lastHeartbeatTime":"2016-10-06T16:53:45Z","lastTransitionTime":"2016-10-06T16:51:04Z","reason":"KubeletHasSufficientDisk","message":"kubelet has sufficient disk space available"},{"type":"MemoryPressure","status":"False","lastHeartbeatTime":"2016-10-06T16:53:45Z","lastTransitionTime":"2016-10-06T16:51:04Z","reason":"KubeletHasSufficientMemory","message":"kubelet has sufficient memory available"},{"type":"Ready","status":"True","lastHeartbeatTime":"2016-10-06T16:53:45Z","lastTransitionTime":"2016-10-06T16:51:05Z","reason":"KubeletReady","message":"kubelet is posting ready status"}],"addresses":[{"type":"LegacyHostIP","address":"10.0.0.5"},{"type":"InternalIP","address":"10.0.0.5"}],"daemonEndpoints":{"kubeletEndpoint":{"Port":10250}},"nodeInfo":{"machineID":"748cfc5d0ac0444e85d1cccb08411403","systemUUID":"2CB10D3F-EBBF-49E1-8FE6-FF888C4427E8","bootID":"c37560e4-ea62-4640-b2ed-f6ba4368716a","kernelVersion":"4.5.0-coreos-r1","osImage":"Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)","containerRuntimeVersion":"docker://1.10.3","kubeletVersion":"v1.3.4+coreos.0","kubeProxyVersion":"v1.3.4+coreos.0","operatingSystem":"linux","architecture":"amd64"},"images":[{"names":["gcr.io/google_containers/hyperkube:v1.3.4"],"sizeBytes":404164189},{"names":["gcr.io/google_containers/pause-amd64:3.0"],"sizeBytes":746888}]}}]}
I1006 09:53:55.886761   55310 meta.go:86] Calling Accessor on non-internal object: *api.NodeList
```

Comment: What's the error message? Can you find the kube-apiserver's log?

Comment: From within the vm running master if I curl the apiserver I get below error, it gives a valid response when the (experimental-keystone-url) option is not included
`k8-kl4claustz-0-mba33azgxoee-kube-master-sdyzjridsdf3 core # curl http://127.0.0.1:8080
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 8080: Connection refused`

Comment: I meant to ask for the error message spit by the kube-apiserver. Can you find its log? It should be a file named "kube-apiserver.log". I never start a cluster on coreOS so I don't know the path to the log in your setup.

Comment: I just learned that apiserver runs as a container via kubelet in coreos. The docker log for the stopped container is below
`I1004 18:28:24.679802       1 genericapiserver.go:606] Will report 10.0.0.4 as public IP address.
F1004 18:28:24.680285       1 server.go:206] Invalid Authentication Config: Auth URL should be secure and start with https`
I tried passing **https** to the `experimental-keystone-url` option and the apiserver does start but I could still use kubectl over http without any authentication and get a response. Do you know the expected behavior here?

Comment: I think this is expected. See [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/6a1622a7236d2ece7ad213476801a605fff0e664/pkg/genericapiserver/options/server_run_options.go#L364-L368), "The port on which to serve unsecured, unauthenticated access. Default 8080. It is assumed that firewall rules are set up such that this port is not reachable from outside of the cluster".

Comment: Where did you run kubectl from?

Comment: I have kubernetes running on OpenStack Magnum and I'm running kubectl from my local machine.

Comment: Could you run kubectl with -v=9, so it will show the url it hits? For me kubectl hits the [SecurePort](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/6a1622a7236d2ece7ad213476801a605fff0e664/pkg/genericapiserver/options/server_run_options.go#L152).

Comment: @caesarxuchao added logs with `v=9`

Comment: Did you supply your auth info to kubectl? I think it will fallback to http if you didn't give it auth info.

Comment: @caesarxuchao no, I was running `kubectl --v=9 -s http://<master_ip>:8080 get nodes`. So is there no way to prevent it falling back to http and only allow username/password login?

Comment: If your build contains this [PR](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/31491), than setting insecurePort to 0 will turn it off.